# Proving $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID without appealing to the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

This is a really vague question, and I'm not even sure how to pose it correctly, but I will do my best.

The Euclidean algorithm works in $\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain; since Euclidean domains are PIDs, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID. I was wondering if there was a way to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID that does not appeal to the Euclidean algorithm (i.e. without assuming $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain) or without showing, during the course of the proof, that the algorithm holds (for an element).

Here's an attempt. Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $a$ be the smallest positive element in $I$. I claim that $I = (a)$. Let $b \in I$ not be a multiple of $a$. We can assume WLOG that $b > 0$ (and so $b > a$ since $a$ is minimal among positive elements), for otherwise we can apply the following argument to $-b \in I$, which is also not a multiple of $a$. Let $A = \{c > 0 \mid \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} : c = b - ka\} \subseteq I$. $A$ is finite and bounded below by $0$, so it has a minimal element $d$. We need to have $d < a$, for otherwise $e = d - a \in A$ would contradict the minimality of $d$. But $d < a$ is a contradiction to the minimality of $a$, and so $b$ has to be a multiple of $a$. Hence $I = (a)$.

The problem I have with this proof is that, during the course of it, we proved that $b = ka + d$ with $d < a$, which is exactly the Euclidean algorithm except for the case $d = 0$, which I tacitly assumed when forcing $b$ to not be a multiple of $a$ and $A$ to have positive elements - a proper proof would have mentioned those cases and thus showed that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain.

First, is there a proof that does not involve this sort of argument? Second, I'm more interested in the following proof theoretic/logical phenomenon. Say $\varphi, \psi$ are two one-variable propositions (doesn't really matter how many variables they have) such that, for all $x$ for which $\varphi(x)$ holds, $\psi(x)$ holds. If $\varphi(y)$ holds (and hence $\psi(y)$ holds), can we prove $\psi(y)$ *without* appealing to the truth of $\varphi(y)$? I'm going to tag this question as `abstract-algebra` as well as `logic`, but let me know if the `logic` tag is inappropriate.

Comment: Would you be interested in a really dumb sledgehammer proof?

Comment: @Qwertiops Please go ahead!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "Euclidean"? It is very natural here.

Comment: I agree that the Euclidean setting is very natural. I was just wondering if, for an appropriate notion of independence, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID independently of its Euclidean structure.

Comment: @lizardknight Alas, my monstrous Algebraic Number Theory proof was built upon foundations of module theory (i.e. free abelian groups) that relies on $\mathbb{Z}$ being a PID.... To be honest I think you're unlikely to find a nice proof that doesn't rely on Euclideanness, but I'd love to be proven wrong!

Comment: @Qwertiops I see, so this still stands unanswered. Thank you for trying, though! I will keep looking for a non-Euclidean-algorithm-relying proof.

Comment: In reference to your question about logic, it is entirely possible that $\psi(y)$ can be proven independently of $\varphi(y)$ for a given instance of $y$. For example, if $\forall x\psi(x)$ is a tautology and $\forall x\varphi(x)$ is not, then $\psi(y)$ can be proven from the logical axioms without reference to $\varphi(y)$.

Comment: i feel like this can be done with any proofs of bezout theorem that doesn't rely on euclidian algorithm

Comment: @Anonymous Mmmh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @Ariana So now the challenge is to find a proof of Bezout's Lemma that does not involve the Euclidean algorithm. That's going to be tough: [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma) are 5 proofs (actually 6, but #4 is not complete so I'm not counting it), and they all require the Euclidean algorithm or the Division Theorem, which is the Euclidean algorithm stopped after one step. I thought they managed to make it with #5 by using the Euclidean algorithm for coprime integers, but it turns out that its proof requires the Division Theorem. Nothing for now, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: @lizardknight Well for some $u,v$, since the positive integers are well ordered there exists some least positive $d$ with $d=xu+yv$. Then we can just prove that $(u,v)=(d)$. It is obvious that $(u,v)\supset(d)$, next show that $d$ is a divisor of $u,v$, then it is obvious that $(u,v)\subset (d)$, hence both ideals are equal. I'll rewrite this to an answer

Comment: actually just noticed it is circular in the $d$ is divisor of $u,v$ step oops:/

Comment: I'm not sure if you would call this Euclidian algorithm but $(x,y)=(z,y)$ for $z$ minimal in $\{k>0|k=x-ny\}$ by well ordering, repeat this process and eventually we get some $(0,d)$, a principal ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following works. I need that there are finitely many classes mod $b$ and Euclid's lemma. The latter can be proved without the algorithm as Euclid did (see second proof here: [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)), while for the former follows from $\mathbb Z$ being cyclic, and everything mod $b$ having order $b$ or less.

Proof:
Let's prove something less first: $\mathbb Z$ is a unique factorization domain. This has a standard proof by Euclid's lemma (a prime divides a product iff it divides some factor. This has a proof via the fact that $a/b$ is a reduced fraction iff $a,b$ are relatively prime iff $a,b$ are minimal).

Now, consider an ideal generated by $(a,b).$ By the above, they have unique factorizations, from which we can read off their greatest common divisor $d.$

We will show that for relatively prime (ie, having gcd $1$) $a,b,$ we have $a^m + nb =1,$ and so $(a,b)=\mathbb Z.$

First, again by Euclids lemma, note that $a^k$ is relatively prime to $b$ for every $k.$ Further there are finitely many residue classes modulo $b.$ This is because $\mathbb Z^+$ is cyclic and hence it's quotients are too (this is from the observation that $(b) +(b) + \ldots =(b).$ See here: [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Group_of_Cyclic_Group)), plus noting that everything mod $b$ has order at most $b.$

So there must be some powers $k< j$ such that $$a^k = a^j + ib$$

This implies

$$a^k (1 - a^{j-k}) = ib$$

But recall $a^k,b$ are relatively prime. So $b$ can't divide $a^k$ and hence must divide $1- a^{j-k}.$ so we have, after rearranging:

$$1= bn + a^{j-k}$$

Which implies that for $a,b$ relatively prime, $1$ is in $(a,b)$ and hence this ideal is $\mathbb Z.$

So by unique factorization and definition of GCD, we can write $$(a,b) = (d)(a/d, b/d)=(d) \mathbb Z =(d)$$ as desired.

Comment: This works! Thank you.